# using more than one run_on_failure keywords with Selenium2Library

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I have noticed, that in Robot framework, I can't have both **Log Source** AND **Capture Page Screenshot**, when I define it in settings "**run_on_failure**".
How do you workaround this, when you want to have both of them?

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own keyword that wraps the two keywords together, and use [Register Keyword To Run On Failure](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Register%20Keyword%20To%20Run%20On%20Failure) to register it as the run on failure keyword.

```
*** Keywords ***

Failure Callback
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Log Source
```

---

And then call this before starting your tests, probably in your test/suite setup

```
Register Keyword To Run On Failure    Failure Callback
```

---

You could also expand Selenium2Library itself, in order to define your wrapper keyword and pass it directly when importing Selenium2Library as the `run_on_failure` argument.